# How can I filter results by category id in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-component

I am trying to render the Bookmark Cards through filtering. I have an event handler that invokes filterByCategory. There, I call on my props to iterate over the collection of bookmarks and return only the BookmarkCards where their category_id matches the value of the e.target; in which the "e.target" is the selected option of the dropdown menu.

Here is my code:

```js
//containers/Bookmarks.js
import React from 'react'
import BookmarkCard from './BookmarkCard'
import BookmarkForm from '../components/BookmarkForm'
import CategoryForm from '../components/CategoryForm'
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem' 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { filterByCategory } from '../actions'


const Bookmarks = (props) => {
  
    
    const renderBookmarkCollection = () => {
        return props.bookmarks.map(bookmark => {
            return <BookmarkCard key={bookmark.id} {...bookmark}/>
        })

    }

    const filterByCategory = (e) => {
        debugger
        props.bookmarks.map((bookmark) => {
            if (bookmark.category_id == e.target.value) {
                return <BookmarkCard key={bookmark.id} category_id={bookmark.category_id} {...bookmark}/> 
            } else {
                return null 
            }
        })
    }
    

    return (
        <div className="bookmarks-container">
            <br></br>
            <BookmarkForm />
            <CategoryForm/>
            <form className="filter-category">
                    <p>FILTER BY CATEGORY</p>
                    <Select id="category-input" value={props.categories} onChange={(e) => filterByCategory(e)}>
                        {props.categories.map(category => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={category.id} name={category.name} value={category.id} >{category.name}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </form>
            <br></br>
            {renderBookmarkCollection()}      
        </div>
    )

}

const mapStateToProps = (currentState) => {
    return {
      bookmarks: currentState.bookmarks.bookmarks,
      categories: currentState.categories.categories
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        filterByCategory: (id) => dispatch(filterByCategory(id))
    }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Bookmarks)
```

With this, I am not returning any "Bookmark cards".

```js
//containers/BookmarkCard.js
import React from 'react'
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete"
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite"
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { deleteBookmark, favoriteBookmark } from '../actions/index'


const BookmarkCard = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory()


    const handleFavorite = () => {
        favoriteBookmark()
        history.push('/bookmarks')
    }

    const handleDelete = () => {
       deleteBookmark()
       history.push('/bookmarks')
    
    }

   

    return (
        <div className="bookmark-card" id={`bookmark-${props.id}`}>
            <h2 className="bookmark-headline">{props.headline}</h2>
                <p className="bookmark-description">{props.description}</p>
                <p className="bookmark-web-url" >{props.web_url}</p>
                <Button 
                    id={props.id}
                    onClick={handleFavorite}
                    className="favorite-button" 
                    startIcon={<FavoriteIcon/>}>
                </Button><br></br>
                <Button
                    id={props.id}
                    size="small"
                    startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
                    onClick={handleDelete}
                    className="delete-button">
                </Button><br></br>
        </div>

    )
}


    
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      deleteBookmark: (id) => dispatch(deleteBookmark(id)),
      favoriteBookmark: (id) => dispatch(favoriteBookmark(id))
    }
}
  
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(BookmarkCard)
```

Comment: On a first render you already don't see the categories? Or only the filter is not working

Comment: @iunfixit on a first render I see all of the BookmarkCards; I do not see the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to return JSX from a callback and this just simply isn't how React works. All that you want to render needs to be returned from the function body of the component.

Add local state to hold the category id filter value and filter the props array inline when rendering.

```
const Bookmarks = (props) => {
  const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = React.useState("");
    
  const renderBookmarkCollection = () => {
    return props.bookmarks
      .filter(bookmark => bookmark.category_id === categoryId))
      .map(bookmark => {
        return <BookmarkCard key={bookmark.id} {...bookmark}/>
      });
  }

  const filterByCategory = (e) => {
    setCategoryId(e.target.value);
  }
    

  return (
    <div className="bookmarks-container">
      <br></br>
      <BookmarkForm />
      <CategoryForm/>
      <form className="filter-category">
        <p>FILTER BY CATEGORY</p>
        <Select
          id="category-input"
          value={props.categories}
          onChange={filterByCategory}
        >
          {props.categories.map(category => {
            return (
              <MenuItem
                key={category.id}
                name={category.name}
                value={category.id}
              >
                {category.name}
              </MenuItem>
            )
          })}
        </Select>
      </form>
      <br></br>
      {renderBookmarkCollection()}      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do I have to use hooks? I am trying to use state globally from the Redux store. I should've mentioned that before.

Comment: @AdriDipietro Since you're not globally storing your search value I don't see any issue with some local state to hold that search value. Unless you actually ***want*** to store the search value in your redux store, and then in that case you will want to select that out of state using the `useSelector` hook and again filter inline before mapping. Or you can select both the bookmarks array ***and*** the search value in the selector and return a filtered array. There are several methods to accomplish this, but they will likely involve storing the search term ***somewhere***.

Comment: @AdriDipietro React component state and redux stores aren't mutually exclusive. The each serve a purpose and use-case.

Comment: Thank you Drew! I understand now. I was hoping to have a stateless component; so I may develop that later on.

Comment: @AdriDipietro I'm afraid you just won't be able to go fully stateless to accomplish this. In React, state and/or props updates are what trigger rerenders, and a rerender is necessary in this case to see the newly filtered data.

Comment: I cannot call .includes() on bookmark.category_id because it is not an array. It is an integer.

Comment: @AdriDipietro Oh, I see, my apologies. I had made the assumption you were filtering by text. I updated the answer to filter by matching a category id.

Comment: Thanks for your help Drew. You have been very informative and kind!

Answer (score 0):

I made it before. I hope my problem solve your.

```
import react, { useState, useEffect }  from 'react';

// This is an array 
const [filteringBookmark, setFilteringBookmark] = useState([]);
// text for you filter
const [ search , setSearch ] = useState('');

// This code output an array maybe complete or filtered while your main 
// array ( bookmarks ) change or text of search change too.
useEffect( () => {
  setFilteringBookmark( bookmarks.filter( book => {
     // filter your text to lowercase if you want  
    return book.includes( search.toLowerCase() )
  }) 
 )
}, [search, bookmarks])
```

So in your jsx it will be like:

```
 <form className="filter-category">
   <p>FILTER BY CATEGORY</p>
   <Select id="category-input" value={props.categories} onChange={(e) => 
    setSearch(e)}
   >
     {filteringBooksmark.map(category => (
      <MenuItem key={category.id} name={category.name} value={category.id} > 
            {category.name}
      </MenuItem>
     )}
   </Select>
 </form>
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score -1):

Map returns a new array, it doesn't change the existing one. Also you shouldn't be attempting to modify props, it is immutable.

Here I put the bookmarks inside a state when the component mounts, when you change categories it will update the state using the original bookmarks passed as a prop, here is an example(I didn't codepen it)

```
const Bookmarks = (props) => {
  const [ bookmarks, setBookmarks ] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setBookmarks(props.bookmarks)
  }, [props.bookmarks])
    
    const renderBookmarkCollection = () => {
      return bookmarks.map(bookmark => {
        return <BookmarkCard key={bookmark.id} {...bookmark}/>
      })
    }

    const filterByCategory = (e) => {
        debugger
        // This is filtering from props.bookmarks, which should be the original array
        setBookmarks(props.bookmarks.map((bookmark) => {
            if (bookmark.category_id == e.target.value) {
                return <BookmarkCard key={bookmark.id} category_id={bookmark.category_id} {...bookmark}/> 
            } else {
                return null 
            }
        }))
    }
    

    return (
        <div className="bookmarks-container">
            <br></br>
            <BookmarkForm />
            <CategoryForm/>
            <form className="filter-category">
                    <p>FILTER BY CATEGORY</p>
                    <Select id="category-input" value={props.categories} onChange={(e) => filterByCategory(e)}>
                        {props.categories.map(category => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={category.id} name={category.name} value={category.id} >{category.name}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </form>
            <br></br>
            {renderBookmarkCollection()}      
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: While I believe this technically works, it is considered anti-pattern to store derived state in React state. See [Thinking in React: Identify The Minimal (but complete) Representation Of UI State](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state) specifically points (1) "Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t state." and (3) "Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it isn’t state."

Comment: I changed OP code to work in a way he designed it, it is not my intention to refactor his code without knowing his intentions for the component